# Accepting gearman jobs with specific conditions

Tags: php, gearman

I am using [Gearman job server](http://gearman.org/) along with [Gearman Manager](https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager). My main task is to distribute the video encoding jobs across several physical servers. I have several workers running on several machines.

Everything seems to run correctly. Now, I have been asked to convert these servers to private server when client requests. A private server(physical machine) is responsible for the video encoding of only those clients who requested it. All other jobs will be processed by other servers.

In Gearman Manager, I have specified the video encoding job in the worker directory. So, at this point, it doesn't have the feature of working as a private server. I want to check the client id and the server id before beginning the process of video encoding. Is there anyway, I can accept jobs with these conditions before I start processing in the worker.

## Possible solutions

1. I thought of changing the worker name, but if large number of clients request private server, then it is impossible to have the workers provisioned in advance.
2. The other way would be allow any worker to process the job and crash the worker if it doesn't belong on this machine.

Both the above solutions are not fit to go into production. Is there any other way out?

Comment: Rather than handling this on the application layer, have you considered creating a separate  instance of the gearman server and only give firewall access to those clients?

Comment: If the number of clients who request private servers becomes very large, then it is not possible to have a separate Gearman server for every client.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that available with Gearman.  Its literally just a medium.  However I'd probably set up a front end worker to handle authentication which then calls another asynchronous job.  However, I still probably wouldn't use Gearman for transporting video data.  The protocol doesn't handle streams, unless you're planning to transport the data in chunks.